# How to get the name of a attribute of an object and its value

Tags: powershell, object, comparator

I am trying to parse parameters of a Graph command to get every value and attribute name. The reason would be to use [Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7.3) between the current state of an object and bodyparams added as JSON or an array in Powershell.

Or even create a simple function to compare any of the old params with the JSON for any change, and create a parms with the differences.

The conceptual idea would be to have a template for any modification without using the commands, the old object's params, to compare with a new set of params from the diff.

So far, I managed to do this :

`Get-MgGroup -GroupId $GroupId | Select-Object * |Convertto-Json`
Which returns :

```
{
    "AcceptedSenders":  null,
    "AllowExternalSenders":  null,
    "AppRoleAssignments":  null,
    "AssignedLabels":  null,
    "AssignedLicenses":  null,
```

(The whole JSON is too long to be put here, and it would be pointless. It's just attributes and objects)

Which is what I'd want. But I would want to do the same with the object itself

*Definition* is where the values are since this command:

`Get-MgGroup -GroupId $GroupId | Select-Object * | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty`
Returns this :

```
Name                          MemberType   Definition                                                                                                                                              
----                          ----------   ----------                                                                                                                                              
AcceptedSenders               NoteProperty object AcceptedSenders=null                                                                                                                             
AdditionalProperties          NoteProperty Dictionary[string,Object] AdditionalProperties=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]                                     
AllowExternalSenders          NoteProperty object AllowExternalSenders=null                                                                                                                        
AppRoleAssignments            NoteProperty object AppRoleAssignments=null                                                                                                                          
AssignedLabels                NoteProperty object AssignedLabels=null                                                                                                                              
AssignedLicenses              NoteProperty object AssignedLicenses=null                                                                                                                            
AutoSubscribeNewMembers       NoteProperty object AutoSubscribeNewMembers=null                                                                                                                     
Calendar                      NoteProperty MicrosoftGraphCalendar Calendar=Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Models.MicrosoftGraphCalendar                                                                
CalendarView                  NoteProperty object CalendarView=null                                                                                                                                
Classification                NoteProperty object Classification=null                                                                                                                              
Conversations                 NoteProperty object Conversations=null                                                                                                                               
CreatedDateTime               NoteProperty datetime CreatedDateTime=04/09/2022 05:48:57                                                                                                            
CreatedOnBehalfOf             NoteProperty MicrosoftGraphDirectoryObject CreatedOnBehalfOf=Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Models.MicrosoftGraphDirectoryObject                                         
DeletedDateTime               NoteProperty objec
```

As you can see, not every value is null or a string, so I cannot just fill an empty object with an iteration of the name with null on it.

In simple terms, I would like to get from the cmd's any "NoteProperty" : the name, the type, and the value.

I figure it might be hard to grasp without context, I wrote a draft on kroki
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckZF2.png)

The idea would have a model for any future change, but I wouldn't want to change it manually every time.

Edit :

I actuall went further and maybe that'll be more evident with the function :

```
function Compare-Attributes {
    
    Get-MgGroup -GroupId $GroupId | Select-Object -Property * | ConvertTo-Json -Compress | Out-file -FilePath 'C:\Users\Currentusr\Currentdir\BodyParams.JSON'

### I change some values 

    $old_parms = @(Get-MgGroup -GroupId $GroupId | Select-Object -Property * | ConvertTo-Json )
    $new_parms = @(Get-Content 'C:\Users\Currentusr\Currentdir\BodyParams.JSON' | Convertfrom-Json )
    
       $new_parms = @(Get-Content 'C:\Users\YassinBousaadi\projects\Ansible\Ansible_Modules\BodyParams.JSON' | Convertfrom-Json | 
        Edit-LeafProperty -PassThru { if ($null -eq $_.Value) { $_.Value = 'null' } } | ConvertTo-Json)


    $old_parms_obj = @( $old_parms| ConvertFrom-Json)
    $new_parms_obj = @( $new_parms | ConvertFrom-Json)
    echo $new_parms_obj
    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $old_parms_obj `
    -DifferenceObject $new_parms_obj `
    -IncludeEqual `
```

What it returns is actually not half bad :

```
InputObject                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
-----------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
@{AcceptedSenders=null; AllowExternalSenders=null; AppRoleAssignments=null; AssignedLabels=null; AssignedLicenses=null; AutoSubscribeNewMembers=null; Calendar=; CalendarView=null; Classification=null; Conversations=null; CreatedDateTime=04/09/2022 05:48:57; CreatedOnB...
```

I changed the AcceptedSenders attribute as true in the JSON in between, so that value should show. but that'll be the one to show, since it's the only one that's changed, right ? I even went and changed every null value to actual null as strings in the JSON because it would otherwise return empty values

Comment: What is your question? Would be better to show an example of what it is you're after.

Comment: I would like to compare two objects, one created from the array of bodyparms I will add @{}, and one coming from the current parms of the same object. So that : 
[passwordprofile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/passwordprofile?view=graph-rest-1.0)

If I create an object from the JSON, I can compare it to the former one in the current profile. Compare each value for any change and output the change for myself.

Comment: Use new-member to add values : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?force_isolation=true&view=powershell-7.3